# LinkedHashMap with different types of data

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap`

My code

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> hmap = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>)data[0];

System.out.println("Contents of LinkedHashMap : " + hmap);

System.out.println("\nValues of map after iterating over it : ");


for (String key : hmap.keySet()) {
     System.out.println(key + ":\t" + hmap.get(key));
  }
```

**Output:**

Values of map after iterating over it : 
cd: PARB
id_inst:PE103AA01
cd_anul:

**Error calling method: generateReport**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

**Contents of LinkedHashMap:**

`{cd=PARB,id_inst=PE103AA01, cd_anul=,  mnt=276562.5, dt_den_theo=2012-01-24 00:00:00, logo=PARB.bmp, id=ISI.model.ParamRecord-1}`

How can I use `String` and `Double` in my `Hashmap` without `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` ?

Comment: Exactly as error says you are trying to cast Double to String in some place. With piece of code you provided it's not possible to find this place.

Comment: Can't see any `Double` key in your map content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have genric types `<String, Object>` with your code, if no, there should be compilaton error at `for (String key : hmap.keySet()) {`, otherwise, it works well.

Comment: yes, that's right, I get a compilation error for that. How should I proceed?

Comment: You have to change it to `for (Object key : hmap.keySet()) {`, and you should convert it to String if you want to use it later  `String keyStr = (String) key`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not that LinkedHashMap can't contain both String and Double instances. It actually perfectly can. The issue is **what** you are doing with those values when you iterate the list. If you try to use the value as a String while it is Double you will get ClassCastException. If all you need is a String instance regarding of the actual object class you could call *toString()* to convert it like this:

```
Object o = hmap.get(key);
String stringVal = (o == null) ? null : o.toString()
```